# Horizontal plane detection in Unity android

Tags: android, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm try to detect the horizontal plane using the camera as seen in the Sony's AR camera like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9nFfXdcOA0. I guess i should be checking out for OpenCV for unity but based on a youtube video I saw ,I felt it is not much accurate.Please suggest me the best option I can go with.I wish I could know how the plane detection was done in Sony's AR camera effect and if that is possible on Unity.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Guess it is not just "plane detection", it is "rectangle plane edges detection". So steps could be like this:

- find edges, filter straight lines (Hough etc), filter longest lines
- use something like RANSAC or any other clasterization to find line group(s) that looks like one plane edges (have almost the same crossing point - for instance)
- filter horizontal planes
- find biggest or closest to the center plane
- find Homography for this plane and add objects accordint to it

To do reverse-engineering one must have this phone to understand algorithm properties via checking it's work for different planes: not rectangle planes, white table on the white floor, white paper on a dark table with edges not parallel to the table edges, circled and elliptical table etc.